# Cannot install php-mbstring on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, composer-php, ubuntu-18.04

I'm using ubuntu 18.04.
I'm trying to install mbstring but terminall show error:

```
php-mbstring : Depends: php7.2-mbstring but it is not going to be installed
```

So I' trying to install php7.2-mbstring but error again:

```
php7.2-mbstring : Depends: php7.2-common (= 7.2.3-1ubuntu1) but 7.2.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 is to be installed
```

Sorry for my bad english.
Anyone have idea how to fix this :(

Comment: So, what about installing the packages in question? What exactly is the problem with that?

Comment: I ran composer install in laravel project and it showed error: the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system. @NicoHaase

Comment: On which architecture do you use your system? According to https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/php7.2-mbstring, the extension depends on 7.2.7 for amd64 and i386, while other architectures only provide 7.2.3 so far...

Comment: php 7.2.7 on a clean 18.04 install (apt install php) -- attempting to install mbstring fails with unable-to-locate error.  Confirmed that it was listed as a package...  if a dependency was missing, you'd get a completely different error...

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you have the "universe" repository enabled for apt-get:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) universe"
```

Answer (score 3):

**Edit the file /etc/apt/sources.list with the next lines:**

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main multiverse restricted universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main multiverse restricted universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main multiverse restricted universe
```

**Save and run:**

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install php7.2-mbstring
```

**And it's done**

Source: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1064634/unable-to-install-php-mbstring